# Fomatted autonumbered text not getting copied from one form to another

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have written a macro to copy data from one textbox in form1 to a textbox in form2.

The textbox in form1 fetches value from a field in DB which is autonumbered and uses the format "FHMY"0000000

My code works but instead of copying the formatted text(number) it just copies the sequence number:

Lets say 13th entry in table associated with form1 is fhmy0000013, but when i use the macro it copies 13 and not the text fhmy0000013.

[image: format]

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command119_Click()

DoCmd.OpenForm "PrinterFhamylabel"

Forms![PrinterFhamyLabel].JOB = Me.JOBNum

Me.JOBNum.SetFocus

End Sub
```

[form2 property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2XDO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the values stored in the table for the column `JOB` are numbers like `13, 14, 15` etc and not `FHMY0000013, FHMY0000014, FHMY0000015`. 
As you can see in the definition of the column, the *Format* attribute is set to `"FHMY"0000000` and this is valid only for presentation purposes. 
So in forms and tables you see `FHMY0000013` when the actual value stored is `13`.
If you want to see in textbox in form2 the copied values formatted you must also change the *Format* of this textbox to: `"FHMY"0000000`
Another case is that in the underlying table of form2 the column represented by the textbox is defined as data type `TEXT`. 
Change it to `Number`.

Comment: I have tried that, but it still shows 13, even after changing the textboxes format to "fhmy"0000000

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. If you change the format to `"FHMY"0000000` you will see the correct value like `FHMY0000013`

Comment: i have added a snapshot (form2 format) in the question, check it..i might be doing something wrong, but i dont know what.

Comment: @NewAtSQL `Format` controls how the field is displayed. It does not affect its underlying value. FWIW you should avoid using PK/ID (autonumber) columns for that purpose - PK should have no meaning whatsoever for anything other than the database engine.

Comment: thanks guys, that worked (changing datatype of form2's table to number instead of text) :)